# Print type(example) always returns string

Tags: python, input, types

```
UserInput = raw_input('Enter something: ')
print type(UserInput)

print (UserInput)
```

This is a very simple piece of code that is supposed to tell me what type the enter input is. e.g int or bool. For some reason It always come up as string. Lets say I enter "1" (no quotes) when I am prompted to "Enter Something". That should return as type int. The problem I think lies in the fact that UserInput is a string "raw_input('Enter something: ')". How do I fix my script to return the type the input that the user gave me? I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `raw_input()` function **always** returns a string, it is [documented as such](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input):

> The function then reads a line from input, **converts it to a string** (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

Emphasis mine.

Perhaps you were looking for [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) instead? It evaluates the input given as a Python expression and is the equivalent of `eval(raw_input())`:

> Equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`.
>
> This function does not catch user errors. If the input is not
>   syntactically valid, a `SyntaxError` will be raised. Other exceptions
>   may be raised if there is an error during evaluation.

If you entered `1`, it'd be interpreted as an integer literal and `type(UserInput)` would print `<type 'int'>`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a bracket here in the second line. To solve the problem try this:

```
UserInput = raw_input('Enter something: ')
print(type(UserInput))
print(UserInput)
```

Comment: This is probably not the problem.